Mount a chainsaw filing vise to a pickup lift gate using a clamp
I have a chainsaw filing vise; it's used to secure a chainsaw while using both hands to carefully file the chain, when working in the bush.

Image source: https://www.leevalley.com/en-ca/shop/tools/workshop/workbenches/vises/70935-chain-saw-filing-vise?item=09A0520

Instead of strapping the vise to a log, or strapping it to a tailgate (too loose), I want to attach the vise to a clamp that can be clamped to a pickup truck lift gate.
The lift gate is similar to this: https://www.amazon.ca/LiftDogg-13006039-2-Piece-Pickup-Liftgate/dp/B00P3OALCU

I suspect the vise wasn't designed with a clamp attached because normal tailgates are unsuitable for clamping, unlike a heavy gauge steel lift gate.

What kind of clamp could I use, and how could I attach it to the vise?

If the chain is to stay on the saw, why not just get a set of soft jaws for your vise. This would allow you to clamp the bar of the saw between the vice jaws without damaging the bar. Then you can rotate the chain freely and get the job done.
For my vise at home, I used some 1/4" aluminum angle "iron" (sorry, I know it's not iron, but that's what I've always called it, lol) with 1" sides. I cut the aluminum to the width of the vise jaws. Place these on the jaws of the vise. As they clamp, they stay in place and protect what you're working on. When not in use, put them in your toolbox, or just clamp them in the jaws of the vise.

Good idea, thanks. In this case, the person (not me) works at a remote job site without easy access to a bench vise.

@User1974 - My apologies, I had misread your question. I thought you were attaching a vise to the tailgate, but you're wanting to mount a clamp to the tailgate.
